# How to state the jQuery.ajax 'data' parameter taking advantages of Ruby data structures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and jQuery 1.6. I am trying to implement an AJAX HTTP request and I have a doubt on stating the `data` parameter of that request.

Let say that I have JavaScript code like the following:

```
$jQ.ajax({
  type:    '...',
  url:     '...',
  data:    '...', // Here I would like to state the 
  error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    ...
  }
});
```

So, I may populate the `data` parameter like this:

```
data: 'a=1&b=2&c=3'
data: '<%= data_value %>' # Example 'data_values' value: a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I read both the Ruby (on Rails) and jQuery documentation and those frameworks seem to deal with data differently: the first "tends to use" hashes, the second an "as-like Json" data or directly a URL query string (as in the above example).

But, **how I should state\handle `data` parameter values for a `jQuery.ajax` request so to pass to it a "converted" Ruby hash? That is, what is the *common pratique* adopted in order to populate the `data` parameter so to take advantage of both jQuery AJAX and Ruby hashes (or some other data structure)?**

---

In few words, what I would like to make is to pass a variable (maybe a Ruby hash) to the jQuery `data` parameter and convert it so to be "compatible" with the jQuery system related to that `data`. Maybe I should use something like the following:

```
# data_value = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
data: '<%= convert_to_ajax_data(data_value) %>'
```

If I use some code like the following

```
data_value.as_json {"layout"=>"false"}
data_value.to_json {"layout":false}
```

it doesn't work as expected.

By using the `to_json` method the problem is that the outputted code is something like the following:

```
data: {&quot;a&quot;:1, &quot;b&quot;:2, &quot;c&quot;:3} # '"' chars are replaced with &quot;
```

*How can I avoid the replacement?*

Comment: Those quotes are perfectly valid JSON! .to_json method does not take a block. There must be something else you are doing wrong. Data for a jQuery ajax call should be serialized like 'key1=value1&key2=value2' so you shouldn't use .to_json there.

Comment: @Mirko - **SOLVED** - I must use something like `raw(data_value.to_json)` in the template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert hashes in Rails to JSON format like this `data.to_json`
All params submitted via JavaScript are just regular `params` hash in Rails.

If you need serialized data in JavaScript just format your hash to a string with something like:

```
hash = { key1: "foo", key2: "bar" }
data = []
hash.each { |key, value| data << "#{key}=#{value}" }
data = data.join("&")
# "key1=foo&key2=bar"
```

Comment: I tried that but the `to_json` method generated `"` characters that jQuery seems do not accept as valid parameters. I updated the question.

Comment: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } is valid JSON.

Comment: But data for jQuery AJAX call should be serialized, not JSON, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: *Read the comment below the question to get the solution.*